# Europe based printing services for low quantity high quality custom printed tiles

Tags: city, moc, customization, afol, printing

I've found many websites providing a service for custom printing of LEGO tiles :

- [United Bricks](https://www.united-bricks.com/bespoke-printing)
- [Brick Engraver](http://www.brickengraver.com/tiles)
- [BrickSanity](https://www.bricksanity.com/collections/custom-prints)
- [Fab-Bricks](https://fab-bricks.com/customprinting/)
- [Citizen Brick](https://citizenbrick.com/pages/custom-printing)
- [EclipseGrafX](https://www.eclipsebricks.com/services/)
- [Minifig Madness](https://www.minifig-madness.com/pages/custom-printing)
- [BrickTactical](https://bricktactical.com/pages/uv-printing)
- ...

I find it very hard to compare these websites, though, and the service they're offering. So I was wondering if there's anyone here who's familiar with these services and who can suggest a website that fits all of these criteria :

- The ability to order small quantities (5 or less) of a particular tile
- The ability to upload your own file in vector format (eg. SVG or EPS)
- The ability to upload your own file in pixel/raster format (eg. JPEG or PNG)
- High-quality prints
- Based in Europe (to keep shipping costs minimal)
- A reasonable price (subjective, I know...)

I'm looking for this because I'd like to add some more life/detail to my city with such printed tiles.

Comment: Would you consider service who can produce custom stickers? It meets all of the criteria, but is a sticker.

Comment: @Alex : No, really, no, I'm sorry. I really hate stickers. I don't even use the stickers that come with the set... which is one of several reasons I'm looking for a way to get my own custom tiles printed : that way, I can replace the official stickered tile with an equivalent printed tile.